# Paypal IPN protocol: Why is the empty HTTP 200 response not send in the examples?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I saw several examples of implementing the Paypal IPN protocol in PHP, like https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/IPN_PHP.txt. It works fine. 
Nevertheless I have a doubt that bothers me.

The documentation on https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/ says:

...
2. PayPal HTTP POSTs your listener an IPN message that notifies you of this event.
3. Your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response.
4. Your listener HTTP POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to PayPal.
...

In the examples I've seen step 3 is skipped and 4 is done right after 2.
Why is that?

Comment: You might want to check standard examples that had implemented Paypal IPN protocol exactly the say way as per paypal developer documents. Are you sure that you are referring to the recommended examples on net?

Comment: The following URL is recommended by Paypal 

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/IPN_PHP.txt

and indeed it is in the official paypal github project, so I guess this are recommended examples. I cannot see that they do step 2 there. Also if I try to execute the example code using the [IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator)  and do an ngrep I cannot see the empty 200 response being send.

On the other hand everything seems to work fine, since I complete all other steps successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 200 is the default response of a PHP script. You don't have to send it, you just have to make sure you don't send anything else!

Similarly for empty: if you don't do an `echo` then your response will be empty.

Comment: Daren, I am also looking for this issue. I am confused in my listener function, If i send emtpy HTTP 200 to paypal. Then how would i process the rest of the things i.e sending back post data to paypal in order to validate.

Answer (score -1):

But I saw it here:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

```
<?php

   // Send an empty HTTP 200 OK response to acknowledge receipt of the notification 
   header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); 
   ...
```